# Blittable Value Types

Tags: c#, interop, pinvoke, marshalling, unmanaged

Here is a list of blittable [types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75dwhxf7.aspx).  It contains Int32 and Int64.  But I don't see just plain "int" on the list.  How does C# treat the plain "int" type?  Does it just get replaced with Int32 or Int64 depending on the system?  Or is there a subtle difference?  Will using "int" ever cause a performance hit for marshalling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int` is an alias for `Int32`. So no, there won't be a performance hit when using one vs. the other.

Comment: It is IntPtr that has different size depending on architecture.

Answer (score 1):

`int` is a C# keyword that maps to the `System.Int32` struct. There are no plans (AFAIK) to migrate it to Int64.